# Unable to make modal validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I had tried to make wizard modal. Before going to second modal the first modal form fields should be validated I tried to make this using jQuery.

I tried to make text box color red when fields are not entered and it turns gray if data is entered into the fields. When I click on save it's going to modalTwo, before going to modal two it should check the mandatory fields.

When i do click on save text, the form should be validated. I mean every input fields should be filled mandatory.

```js
$("#modalOne").modal("show");
$('.modalEditBtn').click(function() {
  if ($('.modalEdit').is('[readonly]')) { //checks if it is already on readonly mode
    $('.modalEdit').prop('readonly', false); //turns the readonly off

  } else { //else we do other things

    var school = document.getElementById('sslc').value;

    if (school == "") {
      document.getElementById('sslc').style.borderColor = "red";
      return false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('sslc').style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
    }

    $('.modalEdit').prop('readonly', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Modal One -->
<div class="modal" id="modalOne">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
              <font color="black">
                <a href="#" style="color: darkred">
                <span style="color: darkred;">&times;</span>
                </a>
               </font>
               </button>
            <label class=" col-sm-4">Edit &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="text">
            <a class="modalEditBtn" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTwo">Save</a>
            </span></label> <br />
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">
                  <div class="form-body">
                    <br />
                    <table class="table table-responsive">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="outside scrollable-menu" style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">
                            <select id="sslc" class="form-control" oninput="this.className = ''">
                              <option hidden value="">10th</option>
                              <option value="a">10th</option>
                              <option value="b">12th</option>
                              <option value="a">Degree</option>
                              <option value="b">Masters</option>
                              <option value="b">Cetificate</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td class="outside scrollable-menu" style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">
                            <select id="inputStream" class="form-control modalEdit">
                              <option hidden value="">Degree</option>
                              <option value="ar">BCA</option>
                              <option value="cm">BSc</option>
                              <option value="sc">BBA</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="outside" style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">Stream
                            <select id="inputStream" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Stream Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                              <option hidden value="">Stream</option>
                              <option value="ar">Arts</option>
                              <option value="cm">Commerce</option>
                              <option value="sc">Science</option>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td class="outside" style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">Institution
                            <select id="inputStream" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Stream Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                              <option hidden value="">Institution</option>
                              <option value="ar">VTU</option>
                              <option value="cm">Anna</option>
                              <option value="sc">Bangalore</option>

                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td class="outside" style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">Yr of Passing <input type="date" class="form-control" id="resizedTextbox" placeholder="Yr of Passing" />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="outside" style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">State
                            <select id="inputState" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('State Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                              <option hidden value="">State</option>
                              <option value="is">Karnataka</option>

                            </select>
                          </td>

                          <td class="outside" style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">Country
                            <select id="inputCountry" class="form-control" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Country Required')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                              <option hidden value="">Country</option>
                              <option value="is">India</option>
                              <option value="is">US</option>

                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td class="outside" style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;"><br>
                            <input type="file" size="80"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Two -->
<div class="modal" id="modalTwo" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="width: 99%; margin-bottom: 2px;">
          <br>
          <center>Do you want add another record</center>
          <br>
          <center>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOne" style="background-color: lightblue; border-color: #edf1ed;">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success " data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalThree" style="background-color: lightblue; border-color: #edf1ed;">No</button>
            <br />
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Two -->
<div class="modal" id="modalThree" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <center>
          <div class="alert alert-info" style="width: 95%; margin-bottom: 2px;">
            <center>NN records saved</center>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="close" style="background-color: lightblue; border-color: #edf1ed;">Ok</button>
            <br />
        </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your snippet returns a js error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: @FabianSchöner I fixed that already. Bootstrap was not included, and there was one missing closing brace

Comment: @Learning What exactly is your problem? Because as far as I can see it works properly.

Comment: Thanks @ Krzysztof Janiszewski.. This code is working fine after edited by  Krzysztof Janiszewski.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski You also changed the code, why? Should have added that as an aswer.

Comment: I did not change the code, just changed it to snippet, and added missing brace

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski Yes you did, see the revision history... You added $("#modalOne").modal("show"); which was not there before.

Comment: Oh, you're right, but that was only to show the modal, because in the example there was no button to open it. I assumed, that this is out of the question.

Comment: Well, I guess the question should be flagged now as "no longer reproduced / typographical error"

Comment: That's what I did almost instantly. The code was correct from the beginning.